# Why some elements of xamarin has a "shadow" when creating page?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, oncreate

I'm using xamarin to build an app android and ios and have noticed that some buttons, webviews and some other elements has a kind of shadow while page is being created and then this "shadow" disappears and everything is fine. It seems to occur with transparent elements and I could fix it by giving negative padding or margin, but it's really annoying and not elegant solution. Does anyone here knows what is happening? I almost forget, this tests are being performed on android, I don't know yet if iOs has same issue.

You guys can see below, the "shadow" is at right of the button(it has transparent background):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After Android 5.0, the default button control on the system will have a shadow，if you don't need the shadow .you could define in your activity theme like below :

```
<item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless</item>
```

Comment: And how about WebView ??? I have tried webViewStyle but visual studio says "Style attribute 'attr/webViewStyle (aka com.App.Beta:attr/webViewStyle)' not found.

Comment: @SandroBenevides could you show  the shadow of the webview ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It was the scrollbars not a border and I could solve that by setting IsEnabled="False"